# iOS: DDL Commands during runtime

Tags: ios, core-data, runtime

i want to add tables/columns to a database during runtime.
Currently I'm using Core Data.
I know that there's a possibility to do so in XCode (add new data model version), but I definitely can't use that way, because I receive the database schema from a web service.

Is there any good possibility to run ddl commands during runtime when using Core Data, or is it just possible with directly using sqlite (or a wrapper/ormapper)?
If it's better to use a wrapper/ormapper please give me some suggestions about which should be used in this case.

Workflow should be:

1. start app
2. check if database is up to date
3. if new version of schema is available from a web service do DDL commands
4. continue with app workflow

PS: Please no answers which describe alternatives modifying the schema with XCode!

Comment: Do you want to modify the data model that Core Data uses, or something else? You say "a database" which sounds like you mean something outside of Core Data, but it's not clear.

Comment: Sorry, yes i want to modify the core data model

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the Core Data model at run time? Yes...but, it probably won't work the way you want it to work.

Core Data's API makes it possible to construct or modify every detail of a data model at run time. Xcode's model editor is a convenience, but you could skip it and do everything in code if you wanted. For example, `NSEntityDescription`'s `properties` attribute (which covers both attributes and relationships) is writeable. You could create a new `NSAttributeDescription` and update the entity's properties to contain it. Bang, you just added a new attribute to the entity. Similarly, `NSManagedObjectModel`'s `entities` property is writeable, so you could create a new `NSEntityDescription` and add it to the model. That gives you a new entity, created at run time.

**But**, and it's a big one: *you can only do this **before** you load the data store*. Once you load your persistent store, altering the model will throw an exception. When Core Data loads a persistent store, it compares the model file to the model used in the store file. They **must** match, and you can't do anything to change this fact after loading the store. Once you load the store, the model is fixed.

What's more, even if you modify your model before loading the persistent store, you can only load persistent stores that match the current version of the model-- unless, that is, you also write code to migrate the persistent store to the new model. How hard that is depends on the nature of the changes. At a minimum then, you would need to make any changes before loading previously saved data, and then also arrange to do model migration to update the persistent store to use the new model.

With Core Data the model (schema) and data are stored separately and matched up when the store is loaded. That's not how SQLite works internally but it's the approach that Core Data enforces.